# Accessing document class from stage

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I could not find a specific solution to my problem. I start my document class "Main.as". From that I play Frame 1, which is my GUI. After I press the "start" Button on my GUI, I want it to call the "Start()" function in my Main.as.

But it just won't work. I found out that I cannot create Objects from my document class, also I can't have more than 1 document class. So what can I do?

Main.as

```
import flash.events.KeyboardEvent;
import flash.events.MouseEvent;
import flash.display.MovieClip;
import flash.events.Event;
import flash.ui.Keyboard;



public class Main extends MovieClip 
{
trace("Im the Main Class");
public var BG:MovieClip;
public var char:Char_Control;
public var enemy:Enemy;
var blockSlide:Boolean = true;
var coin_array:Array = new Array();
var char_array:Array = new Array();
var coin:item_collider;
var posx;
var posy;
var oCollider;
var main:Main = new Main();


    //Konstruktor
    public function Main() 
    {
    trace("Im the Main Class(Constructor)");
    this.stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN, keyPressed);
    this.stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_UP, keyReleased);
    this.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, Gravity);
    this.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME,update);
    gotoAndPlay(1); // Starts GUI
    Start(); // Starts Everything else => The Game itself
    }



public function update(_event:Event)
{
    //Execute Base_Class
    //char.Move();

    //Execute Base_Class+Sub_Class
    enemy.Chase(char,enemy);
    //enemy.Move(true, "walk");
}




public function Start()
{
    // Adds Character to Stage
     char = new Char_Control(875,350);
     stage.addChild(char);

     enemy = new Enemy(500,450);
     stage.addChild(enemy);

     char_array[1]=char;
     char_array[0]=enemy;

    // Adds Objects to Stage
    for (var i2:int=1; i2<30; i2++)
     {
     posx = Math.round(Math.random()*(1400)+1);
     posy = Math.round(Math.random()*(800)+1);
     coin = new item_collider(posx,posy);// Öffnet Konstruktor
     stage.addChild(coin);
     trace("Add Coin (foreach)");
     coin_array.push(coin);
     }
}
```

stage:

```
button.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK,buttonClick);

var tform:TextFormat = new TextFormat();
tform.size = 20;
tform.font = "Arial";
tform.align = TextFormatAlign.CENTER;
tform.color = 0x000000;
tform.bold = true;

var tfield:TextField = new TextField();
tfield.width = checkbox.width;
tfield.width = button.width;
tfield.width = coin_number.width;
tfield.width = stepper_label.width;
tfield.x = 0;
tfield.y = 30;

var coin_amount:int = 0;
var create_enemy:Boolean = false;

tfield.setTextFormat(tform);
addChild(tfield);

checkbox.setStyle("textFormat",tform);
button.setStyle("textFormat",tform);
coin_number.setStyle("textFormat",tform);
stepper_label.setStyle("textFormat",tform);





stop();
function buttonClick(e:MouseEvent) 
        { 
        coin_amount = coin_number.value;
        create_enemy = checkbox.selected;
        nextFrame(); //Next Frame => the Level itself
    }
```

Comment: While it is true that you can only have one document class, you absolutely *should* be able to instantiate objects from that class. What is your specific issue/error? It looks like you're calling `Start` directly in your constructor instead of via an event listener on your start button.

Comment: I want to call start () from an non-extern script in the first frame of my stage. I don't get an error, but after "gotoAndPlay(1)" it executes the script on my stage. Then it jumps to the next Frame in which i have my background (before i had my main class here but now i want it to be extern). And here is my problem. How can i call my document class "Main.as" from the second frame of my stage?

Comment: You really shouldn't mix timeline code and external class code. You can place any of your timeline code you have in your Document Class. That being said, your Document Class is actually the code for your entire application. Therefore, anything you put in your document class should be accessible by the timeline. I think your `gotoAndPlay(1)` is unecessary, you probably just want to put a `stop()` somewhere on your first frame.

Comment: Well, without gotoAndPlay(1) it won't call the first frame (my GUI).Also we HAVE to do this. Its part of an project and we need that mix for an A-grade. Isn't there a way to call gotoAndPlay(1) and jump back to Main.as after buttonClick?

Comment: I'm confused by what you're asking. There is not need to "jump back" to Main.as. Main.as is your Document Class, it is persistent throughout your application.

Comment: but it won't start the "start()" function by itself. I have to call it to initialize the characters and objects of my game. The moment i call my GUI my game is frozen...

Comment: Well we seem to have an understanding problem here...lets try something different. I put it back to a state where it worked. The Main.as is now at frame 2 of my time line. I want that frame 2 as my document class... how can i do that? I uploaded the whole thing since the code alone might not be enough to explain... https://www.dropbox.com/s/jxt8kwkagox3qxc/A10_new.rar

Answer (score 0):

After downloading your code, I notice that there are a few compatibility issues with the way you've set up your timeline code and the code intended to be the Document Class.

Although you have "Automatically declare stage instances" *unchecked* in your AS3.0 settings, you appear to have a mix of implicitly-declared and explicitly-declared instances on the stage. To resolve this, I would suggest leaving this property unchecked and declaring all stage instances in your Document Class (this includes anything you have on the stage in frame 1 as well: `coin_number`, `checkbox`, etc).

Doing this will also require you to import any classes you are using (i.e. `NumericStepper`, `TextField`, `TextFormat`, etc).

Once you have done this, you'll want to move the game control event listeners (the ones you have in your Document Class constructor). You can place these either in a separate method or add them to the end of your `Start` method. If you leave them in the constructor, you'll be attempting to access something that does yet exist because your `update` method that is called on `ENTER_FRAME` relies on objects that get instantiated in the `Start` method.

The next step is to *not* call `Start` from your constructor. Instead, place a call to `Start` on your second frame.

This should get your application to a runnable state using a mix of timeline code and a Document Class.

I would like to know why this is a requirement for a good grade as this is highly unorthodox and--for the most part--looked down upon in the ActionScript community.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I really appreciate that you took the time to look so deep into my code. I will this this but I think I understand my problem now. The professor said we may skip 1 out of 13 tasks to get an A. Maybe this is because its not good to mix up those 2, but I'm not really sure. I'm also remembering him telling us to mix up those 2 to get an better overview. :>